# database is not update to true based on datetime c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code that needed to update to true in database after one hour the browser is open but the thing is the database is not updated to True (by default it is false). Please help me figure out the error. I am new to C# .

```
DateTime dtt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
//after 1 hour update to true
if(DateTime.Now > dtt)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("....");

        string selectQuery = @"UPDATE tester SET have_test = 'T'";
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
else
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("...");

        string selectQuery = @"UPDATE tester SET have_test = 'F'";
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Can you make sure the connection opens fine? And, may be not related but do you want to update all records in the table after 1 hour?

Comment: You have to actually wait for the time to increase. Basically what you've done is: `int a = 3; int b = a + 2; if (a > b) { /* Why would you expect this to ever happen? */ }` If you do actually have some timer, loop, event, or whatever somewhere, you should include it with the rest of your code.

Comment: Also, what "browser" are you talking about? This is a winforms app. Does this have something to do with a `WebBrowser` control somehow?

Comment: I actually just read the code itself, the logic is wrong, it'll never get to the `if()` body.

Comment: C# doesn't block until the time reaches the desired time. Between setting `dtt` and comparing it to `Now`, I doubt that even a millisecond would elapse. So, assuming the time is 12:00:00, and you set `dtt` to 12:00:00 + 1 hour, you end up with 13:00:00. On the next line, while the time is still 12:00:00, you ask "is 12:00:00 after 13:00:00?"

Comment: @Ghukas I dont want to update all records in the table after 1 hour, it should be update one particular tester based in textbox. I only show the logic and trying to get some idea to fix it

Comment: @itsme86 im using the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("google.com");

Comment: If you want to hit the if condition, try  DateTime dtt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);

Comment: If your using windows forms :: add timer control and put all this code on timer tick event and set the timer tick value to 1000*60*60 = 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dtt = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
//after 1 hour update to true
if(DateTime.Now > dtt)
....
```

This is never achieved as not the places you are using 'DateTime.Now' which would give the same time, you need to store the datetime value at the start of the browser and then use that value in the if condition to compare if its been an hour or not.

Answer (score 0):

if it's winforms

put a timer control on your form
set the timer tick that is 1000 = 1sec

to say

1000*60*60 = one hour

and on timer control tick event put your above code

it will be called right after every hour